# How can I prevent Chrome from hiding the Windows Taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, taskbar

When I'm using Chrome I have to hit the `Windows key` whenever I want to show the taskbar.

Is there a way to prevent Chrome from hiding it in the first place.

On every other application when I move my cursor to the bottom of the screen the taskbar (which I have set to `auto-hide`) appears. Only Chrome requires me to press a key to see it.

On occasions when I have to use items on the taskbar frequently, it becomes a pain to have to press the `Windows key` every time.

I Googled on this and found someone who managed to fix this issue by applying a theme to Chrome from the Themes Gallery. This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Google Chrome in full screen mode, the task bar is unavailable there. Press <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Alternative, you could have this problem: [Google Chrome: Always On Top Bug](https://superuser.com/q/238975/9666)

Comment: Tom.
I had the same problem and it's been plaqueing me for days! I read your answer pressed F11 and Wella problem solved! Now that's how problems should be solved by "TRUE" professionals!

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the taskbar and make sure *Lock the taskbar* is ticked.