# Chrome is now always on top, how can I avoid that?

Tags: google-chrome

I sometimes open the Run dialog in order to type something while watching a video. It is my "notepad". Since the new version of Chrome (currently 60.0.3112.113) Chrome is always on top on my Windows 10 system. How can I make the Run dialog be on top of Chrome again?

Note: Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> twice like described in the post [Google Chrome: Always On Top Bug](https://superuser.com/questions/238975/google-chrome-always-on-top-bug) does not solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried [Chromium](https://chromium.woolyss.com/), the public-domain version of Chrome? I use version 60 on Linux without problems, and there are no apparent add-on compatibility issues, but maybe the always-on-top bug is only on Windows. You can use the portable version to check it out quickly.

Comment: I was using it on Linux. Good point. Last restart of Chrome fixed the problem by the way. Seems that some other software (installation) was the problem.

Comment: "Have you tried Chromium,?????????"
Surely you gest!
You really think I'm gonna load a different version of a browser just to fix what should be a "toggle" setting in "REAL" Chrome?
Try this instead......
1. Go to Chrome Settings. 
2. Scroll down to On Startup
3. Select "Continue where you left off"
4. Shut down Chrome
5. Reopen.
6. Chrome will no longer "insist" on being ON TOP.
7. You're welcome. :-)

Comment: I'm having exact same issue for multiple Chromium-based applications: Chrome browser, Brave browser, Dissenter browser, Visual Studio Code. It just happens randomly now and again to a window of those applications I have open, and I need to restart to fix it.

Comment: @MichaelScott, Thank you. Worked perfectly. Wasted a lot of time trying other things. Please try this for anyone who faced the same issue.

Answer (score 63):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

I Had that problem as well.  Some YouTube comment revealed that combo to me, so I tried it and it worked.

Using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: as of 6/11/2019 this key combination is not working for me.

Comment: I tried the F11 thing above too.  But closing all of my chrome windows and reopening worked!  That was annoying.

Comment: While the shortcut works, the problem occasionally comes back. Very annoying. Is this caused by Windows or by Chrome?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I windowed chrome and moved another window and chrome was still on top. Very annoying having to minimize every single time I want to see something other than chrome. However what did work was closing chrome and restarting, with the same tabs open.

Comment: Funny. I had this problem in Linux with Brave browser (based on Chromium), and the solution was the same key combo! So it must be something in the browser.

Comment: Combo does not work for me

Comment: Don't work for Ubuntu+Chrome for me.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Maybe I should ask it as a separate question but any simple way to go back to Chrome always being on front pressing the same key combination again does not work.

Comment: 6/23/2021 - Not working for me

Answer (score 9):

I had one of my Chrome windows always on top while the other behaved as usual.
None of workarounds mentioned here helped to cure the problematic window.

Then I closed it with <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd>, switched to the second unaffected Chrome window and pressed <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd> to reoped all just closed tabs. This helped in my case.

Comment: I ran into this strange problem as well (using Chromium 80 in Linux). To be safer you can right click in the empty space of the tab bar and 'Bookmark all tabs' to a folder first and then right click the folder and 'Open all' in a new window. Or, what worked for me, was to simply open a new window with ctrl+n and drag my few open tabs over to it.

Comment: Closing the current window always fixes the problem temporarily, but it then eventually comes back. Perhaps it's a symptom of keeping Chrome continuously open for longer then it should be! I have startup set to 'continue where you left off' so all my taps reopen when I reopen Chrome. Note I'm running Canary (and this issue has persisted over many updates).

Comment: Also note the problem I'm having isn't a matter of 'focus'; when experiencing this bug, I can have another window in 'focus' (so accepting the keyboard input) but all I will see is Chrome (if it is maximised). This also applies to other Chrome windows (so new Chrome windows which are opened might take focus but won't be visible until I minimise the problematic Chrome window). Certain windows which 'force' themselves on top can still be seen over the Chrome window.

Answer (score 4):

I use PowerToys from Microsoft and the shortcut is Win+Ctrl+T

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reset chrome settings to default, advanced clear history worked for me. Only thing is it removes all of your extensions and themes.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. I tried the other answers (as of this comment date) and this is what I had to resort to unfortunately.

Comment: Tried reinstalling Chrome and then removing all extensions, developer mode, and installed them one by one back to find the buggy extension to fix the problem.