# Grey Chrome TitleBar After Hibernate

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, nvidia-graphics-card, hibernate, title-bar

Happens with the older NVIDIA Card in an occasional resume from hibernation. Curiously, the close, minimize and restore buttons are not available, although the window can be moved with the mouse, and double clicking the titlebar will still maximize/restore it.
Suspected to be related to the events resulting from the [interaction of Windows Boot out of hibernation and NVIDIA drivers](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/960202/dwm-and-nvidia-issue-since-win-10-aniv-edition-update-screen-goes-black-fo-r-a-second-and-magifire-/?offset=7#5335766).
Very seldomly, but possibly related, a tabbed group of Chrome windows will also flash if it has adopted the [on top condition](https://superuser.com/questions/238975/google-chrome-always-on-top-bug) before the hibernation, becoming unusable, and requiring a Chrome restart.
The "Use hardware acceleration when available" option in Chrome is turned on.
How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Chrome is the most obvious.
Turning off the "Use hardware acceleration when available" option in Chrome is an option, also requiring the Chrome restart.
As H/W acceleration is desirable, the only way to properly resolve this condition is to debug it with [BCDedit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--bootdebug).
Update: *Hibernate* initiated from a legacy keyboard appears to affect the bootup sequence in *Resume* somehow. More info at this [Logitech post](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360032601473-Y-SE8-Setpoint-and-Windows-10-Hibernation-issue).

Comment: Curiouser & curiouser: with the H/W acceleration off, the title bar, after hibernation resume, may now appear as black, with the left-right-bottom borders of the tabbed group rendering [pale blue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/rOG9z0_5SAw)- which turn [black](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/3C1YPjD7-Fg) whenever the tabbed group window is moved.